# Bootstrap file is not include in custom wordpress plugin

Tags: wordpress, plugins, syntax-error

i'm trying to add bootstrap file into my custm wordpress plugin but not succeeded. i included this "function my_plugin_scripts() {
if( is_admin() ){
wp_enqueue_script('admin_js_bootstrap',$plugin_url.'admin/js/bootstrap.min.js',false,'3.3.7',false);
wp_enqueue_style('admin_css_bootstrap', $plugin_url.'admin/css/bootstrap.min.css',true,'3.3.7','all');
}
}
add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'my_plugin_scripts' );"

and

" add_action( 'wp_print_styles', 'add_my_plugin_stylesheet' );
function add_my_plugin_stylesheet() {
wp_register_style('mypluginstylesheet', '/wp-content/plugins/postgrid/style.css');

wp_register_style('prefix_bootstrap', '//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css');
wp_enqueue_style('mypluginstylesheet');
wp_enqueue_style('prefix_bootstrap');"

codes and others codes but not work.

Here is screenshot of the code [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rBNsU.png)

Please help me here and guide me where to add code on plugin file or functions.php file.

Thank you.

i need a perfect solution for it.

Answer (score 0):

In a plugin (inside a PHP class)

Assumes the Plugin class name is 'my_plugin'.
Assumes the Plugin directory is named 'my-plugin'.
Assumes the Plugin style sheet is named 'plugin.css'.

```
<?php
class WPDocs_My_Plugin_Stylesheet {

    /**
     * Constructor.
     */
    function __construct() {
        // Register stylesheet.
        add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', array( $this, 'register_plugin_styles' ) );
    }

    /**
     * Registers and enqueues stylesheet.
     */
    public function register_plugin_styles() {
        wp_register_style( 'my-plugin', plugins_url( 'my-plugin/css/plugin.css' ) );
        wp_enqueue_style( 'my-plugin' );
    }
}
new WPDocs_My_Plugin_Stylesheet();
```

Reference [wp_register_style](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_register_style/)